# A specifc solution to Cauchy-Euler differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find $\alpha$ such as $y=x^\alpha$ is a solution to the differential
>   equation $$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x(1-x)\frac{dy}{dx}-(x+1)y=0$$

*(Oxford (2002), modified)*

---

We can derivate and obtaint

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\alpha x^{\alpha - 1} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \alpha (\alpha - 1) x^{\alpha - 2}$$
By substituing the result in the ODE, we get
$$\alpha(\alpha-1)x^2 x^{\alpha-2}+\alpha (1-x)x x^{\alpha-1}-(x+1)x^{\alpha}=0 \\
x^{\alpha}\left(\alpha(\alpha-1)+\alpha(1-x)-(1+x)\right)=0 \\
\alpha^2-\alpha x + x - 1 = 0$$

What can I do after that?

Comment: How did you get your equation at the end? I got $\alpha  (\alpha -x) x^{\alpha }-(x+1)$. Did you perhaps copy the equation here incorrectly?

Comment: Is the equation meant to be $\dots-(x+1)y=0$? I think you left out the $y$. Without it the question makes no sense because there is no solution as required.

Comment: You're right. My mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: So you are almost there. That gives $\alpha^2-1=(\alpha+1)x$. So either $\alpha=-1$ or $x=\alpha-1$. The latter makes no sense, so we must have $\alpha=-1$. It is easy to check that $\frac{A}{x}$ is indeed a solution.

Comment: Why do we rearrange the equation like $\alpha^2-1=(\alpha-1)x$.

Comment: Can we simplify it like $\alpha + 1 = x$.